# SELECT records from two Tables based on a Column value from a Third table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following Table with two Records:

```
   tableAB
[id - tid - t]
[1  - 1   - 1]
[2  - 1   - 2]
```

And Have those two following Tables with a Record:

```
     tableA
[id    -    name]
[1     -    mark]

      tableB
[id -  Aid -  age]
[1  -  1   -  22 ]
```

---

What I want to do is like the following:

1. `SELECT` **from** `tableA` the **Column** `name`
2. `SELECT` **from** `tableB` the **Column** `age` and the **Column** `name` from `tableA` based on `Aid`

---

Using the `tableAB`

if the **Column** `t` is equal to `1` Then the *Query* `SELECT`s the records **from** `tableA` and if it is equal to `2` Then it `SELECT`s the records **from** `tableB`

The Column `tid` is related to each of the two Tables `tableA, tableB` **Column** `id`

---

What I want to do is to `SELECT` the records using the `tableAB` based on the value of **Column** `t` from each **Table** if exists,

How can I do that and What is the possible methods to do that?

---

I think I expected from SQL to fetch it like this

```
[id -  name - age ]
[1  -  mark - null]
[1  -  mark - 22  ]
[2  -  mario- null]
[2  -  mario- 22  ]
[3  -  max  - null]
[3  -  max  - 22  ]
```

But I don't know if that a good form of fetching having `null` on **Column** `age` even while the `tableA` doesn't have the **Column** `age`

Here is the Table in **Fiddle** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pHaER8RhA6kqxvDVVjtWUu/6 with the provided answers before adding it.

Comment: You should include the results that you want in the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff added the expected SQL result now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   select ifnull(a.id,b.id) id,b.age,ifnull(a.name,(select name from tableA where id=b.aid))name
from tableAB ab left join
     tableA a
     on ab.t = 1 and ab.tid = a.id 
     left join
     tableB b
     on ab.t = 2 and ab.tid = b.id;
```

Comment: I've added a Fiddle to make the edit easier, In your query I go no results at all because of the `where clause`, but removing it returns same value with each other query provided in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the following:

```
select ab.*, a.name, b.age
from tableab ab left join
     tablea a
     on ab.t = 1 and ab.tid = a.id left join
     tableb b
     on ab.t = 2 and ab.tid = b.id;
```

Comment: I've made a Fiddle Table in case it makes the editing easier, The results I got from your query was correct except the second row that has the `age` it got the `name` value `null`

Answer (score 1):

This

```
select
tableAB.ID tab_id,
tableA.name taba_name,
null tabb_age
from 
tableAB inner join tableA on tableAB.id = tableA.id 
where tableAB.T = 1 

union all 

select
tableAB.ID tab_id,
null taba_name,
tableB.age tabb_age
from 
tableAB inner join tableB on tableAB.id = tableB.id 
where tableAB.T = 2
```

would produce:

```
TAB_ID  TABA_NAME    TABB_AGE
1          mark      
1                     22
```

Comment: I've added a Fiddle table to make the editing easier, I would like to have the produced value in the second row on `TABA_NAME` = `mark` too since it is built on the `Aid`, Also I acutally got a one row.

Answer (score 1):

```
select tab.id, ta.name, null from tableAB as tab
left join tableA as ta on tab.tid = ta.id
where tabl.t = 1

union all

select tab.id, ta.name, tb.age from tableAB as tab
left join tableB as tb on tab.tid = tb.id
left join tableA as ta on tb.aid = ta.id
where tab.t = 2
```

OR

```
select

tab.id,
ifnull(ta.name, ta2.name)
tb.age

from tableAB as tab
left join tableA as ta on tab.t = 1 and tab.tid = ta.id
left join tableB as tb on tab.t = 2 and tab.tid = tb.id
left join tableA as ta2 on tb.aid = ta2.id
```